# Finding mean of consecutive column data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:
(the data given here is just representational)

[image]    `

I want to do the following with this data:

1. I want to get column only after the 201
   i.e. I want to remove the 200-1 to 200-4 column data.
   One way to do this is to retrieve only the required column while reading the data from excel, but I want to know how we can filter the column name on the basis of a particular pattern as 200-1 to 200-4 column name has pattern 200-*
2. I want to make a column after 202-4 which stores the values in the following ways:
3. 201q1= mean of (201-1 and 201-2)
4. 201q2 = mean of(201-3 and 201-4)

Similarly, if 202-1 to 201-4 data would have been there, a similar column should have been formed.

Please help.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Hey there! This is a difficult question to answer because there are many criteria to getting you a solution. Since there are distinct questions for your problem, you should break them out into separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough example but it will get you close. The example assume that there are always four columns per group:

```
#sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,12), columns=['200-1','200-2','200-3','200-4', '201-1', '201-2', '201-3','201-4', '202-1', '202-2', '202-3','202-4'])

# remove 200-* columns
df2 = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('200-')]]

# us np.arange to create groups
new = df2.groupby(np.arange(len(df2.columns))//2, axis=1).mean()

# rename columns
new.columns = [f'{v}{k}' for v,k in zip([x[:3] for x in df2.columns[::2]], ['q1','q2']*int(len(df2.columns[::2])/2))]

# join
df2.join(new)

      201-1     201-2     201-3     201-4     202-1     202-2     202-3  \
0  0.865408 -2.301539  1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039 -0.249370  1.462108   
1 -0.172428 -0.877858  0.042214  0.582815 -1.100619  1.144724  0.901591   

      202-4     201q1     201q2     202q1     202q2  
0 -2.060141 -0.718066  0.491802  0.034834 -0.299016  
1  0.502494 -0.525143  0.312514  0.022052  0.702043
```

Answer (score 0):

For step 1, you can get away with list comprehension, and the pandas drop function:

```
dropcols = [x for x in df.columns if '200-' in x]
df.drop(dropcols, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Steps 3 and 4 are similar, you could calculate the rolling mean of the columns:

```
df2 = df.rolling(2, axis = 1).mean() # creates rolling mean
df2.columns = [x.replace('-', 'q') for x in df2.columns] # renames the columns
dfans = pd.concat([df, df2], axis = 1) # concatenate the columns together
```

Now, you just need to remove the columns that you dont want and rename them.

Comment: Thanks .I will check it and let u know